# How to check if my Python object in Matlab was changed by deserializing?

Tags: python, matlab

I am currently writing a Matlab (2016a) program that interacts with Python using the `py` commands in Matlab. I pass input data from Matlab to Python, preprocess it in Python, run calculations in Python and then pass the results back to Matlab.

Now I want to be able to export the preprocessed input to a `.json` file, so I keep an instance of my Python object and export the file on demand. I can also save and load the Matlab program's state to/from `.mat`, but the Python object is no longer valid then (which is also noted in the documentation). See the following example:

```
> s = struct('a', 1, 'b', 2);
> d = py.dict(s);
> py.print(d)
{'a': 1.0, 'b': 2.0}
> save 'd:\example.mat' 'd'
> load 'd:\example.mat'
> py.print(d)
{}
```

In this case it is quite easy to see to see that `d` is empty. In my case I do not use a dictionary, but a more complex object which works with all its functions after loading, but the data just seems to be empty.

Is there a way to determine whether a Python object in Matlab workspace is in its original state or was altered by saving and loading? My preferred way would be that Matlab would throw a catchable exception when trying to load a Python object.